# How to post a string in the body of a post request with Angular 4.3 HttpClient?

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

We've got a .net WebAPI which looks for a filepath string in the body of a post request and returns the corresponding image. I'm struggling to successfully pass a string to it from Angular 4.3 using the new httpClient. Is it possible? The endpoint's being used by other stuff so I don't really want to create a 'model' of... a string just so I can basically duplicate it but pass it json if possible.

WebAPI method signature:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ImagesFromPaths(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] string path)
```

Current service method:

```
getImage(path: string): Observable<any> {

  return this.http.post(
    `${apiUrl}`,
    { path },
    { headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }), responseType: 'blob',
  })
}
```

Got to be an easy thing to achieve?

Answer (score 31):

There is almost everything good with your code. Main issue is `Content-Type` header. If you want to send string to `.NET` REST API with `[FromBody]` annotation and use `application/json` header value you should add `""` to your path param for example `"test_value"`:

```
return this.http.post(
  `${apiUrl}`,
    `\"${path}\"` ,
  { headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }), responseType: 'blob',
  })
```

You can also use `x-www-form-urlencoded` header value. Then you must pass your param to request body in that way:

```
return this.http.post(
  `${apiUrl}`,
    `=${path}` ,
  { headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }), responseType: 'blob',
  })
```

Comment: Adding quotes is cumbersome and when using Swagger generated code not even possible. I have created an HTTP interceptor that adds quotes automatically when you pass just a string and use content-type `application/json`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323899/why-serializebody-method-in-request-ts-does-not-convert-json-stringifythis-body/66209414#66209414

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `path` from `query` by removing `[fromBody]` attribute

```
public HttpResponseMessage ImagesFromPaths(HttpRequestMessage request, string path)
```

and in post send path in `post` request `${apiUrl}/${path}`:

```
return this.http.post(
  `${apiUrl}/${path}`,
  { headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }), responseType: 'blob',
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried another altrnative way by this options and directing posting String path Json to body of post method.

```
 getImage(path: string) {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.post('${apiUrl}',path, options)
                .map((res) => res.json()).share()
                .subscribe(res => {
                  resolve(res)
                }, (err) => {
                  reject(err);
                });
            });
          }
```

I would be happy if it works.Thanks