# Why serializeBody method in request.ts does not convert JSON.stringify(this.body) in case string?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

When i pass `string` value into post method, this value was not converted `JSON`.
So We could not get this value in Controller.

I checked following code and find the reason why value was not converted.

[Link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L255)

But I could not understand this behavior is correct.

```js
apply(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post<boolean>(
      REQUEST_URL + '/applicationrequest',
      id,
      HEADERS
    );
  }
```

```java
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/applicationrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean apply(@RequestBody UUID id) {
        return usecase.apply(id);
    }
```

I want to know the reason why `string` should not be converted `JSON` automatically.
And if way to use `httpClient`, I want to know the correct way to use.
Thank you.

Angular Version is 8.1.0.
Java is Java 8.
Spring is 5.1 / Spring Boot 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because those are 2 totally different things. Angular (or the httpclient) can't know by magic what exactly the endpoint requires or expects as input.

It's simply up to you as a developer to generate the http request that matches the server's interface.

Comment: Thank you for the response. but so why `boolean` value always convert into `JSON`?

Comment: I don't agree with you, because when the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json` (or `text/json`) it's clear that the body should be serialized as a JSON string.

Answer (score 4):

Someone in my team also discovered this issue and we needed to add `JSON.stringify(...)` for all HTTP PUT/POST methods that only accept a string in the body. Our generated proxies (we use Swagger) didn't add this for us.

The actual problem is here in the [Angular code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e3f09ce845cef9fd2c89d39d0d822114c51e68fa/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L255):

```js
/**
* Transform the free-form body into a serialized format suitable for
* transmission to the server.
*/
serializeBody(): ArrayBuffer | Blob | FormData | string | null {
    // If no body is present, no need to serialize it.
    if (this.body === null) {
        return null;
    }
    // Check whether the body is already in a serialized form. If so,
    // it can just be returned directly.
    if (isArrayBuffer(this.body) || isBlob(this.body) || isFormData(this.body) ||
        typeof this.body === 'string') {
        return this.body;
    }
    // Check whether the body is an instance of HttpUrlEncodedParams.
    if (this.body instanceof HttpParams) {
        return this.body.toString();
    }
    // Check whether the body is an object or array, and serialize with JSON if so.
    if (typeof this.body === 'object' || typeof this.body === 'boolean' ||
        Array.isArray(this.body)) {
        return JSON.stringify(this.body);
    }
    // Fall back on toString() for everything else.
    return (this.body as any).toString();
}
```

A normal string will use the last option and will be rendered as a plain string, instead of going through `JSON.stringify`.

I created an [HTTP interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) that checks the content-type and if it's set to `application/json` or `text/json` and the body is a plain string, then the interceptor calls `JSON.stringify` to make sure it's a valid JSON string. This interceptor looks like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class StringInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (typeof request.body === 'string') {     
        const contentType = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
        if (contentType == 'application/json' || contentType == 'text/json') {
            request = request.clone({
                body: JSON.stringify(request.body)
            });
        }
    }

    return next.handle(request)
  }
}
```

You also need to register the interceptor by adding the following code in `app.module.ts` (make sure you import your interceptor) to the provider registration:

```
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: StringInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
```

Also make sure you remove your own `JSON.stringify(...)` calls to avoid that all your strings will have excessive quotes.