# Angular Posting a string to a MVC controller

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently looking at Angular for the first time and trying to post a simple string to an MVC controller. However, when I try to post the string using the Angular client, I get a bad request response.

Test Class:

```
public class Test 
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Posting via Angular client:

```
this.client.post<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'weatherforecast/Test', { Email: Email });
```

This results in a bad request response.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public bool Test([FromBody] string Email)
{
    if (Email == "TestInput")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However this works:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public bool Test([FromBody] Test EmailObject)
{
    if (EmailObject.Email == "TestInput")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I try posting the JSON as simply "StringValue" instead of { Email: "StringValue" }, I get an Unsupported Media Type response.

I imagine there is a simple solution, but is there a way to allow a string to be posted to an MVC controller without requiring it to be passed in as a class?

Comment: the string gets unquoted before being sent, and therefore is invalid

Answer (score 2):

A typical endpoint returns an `IActionResult` or an implementation of `IActionResult`. For example `Ok()`, which translates to an HTTP 200 response, `NotFound` translates to HTTP 404.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody] Test EmailObject)
{
    if (EmailObject.Email == "TestInput")
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
    return Ok(false);
}
```

Pretty sure you have to wrap it in an object in order to post it. That isn't a limitation of ASP.NET Core, but rather a rule of JavaScript in general. Simply typing `"StringValue"` is not valid JSON, but `{ Email:Email }` is.

Side note:

You could use query strings:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public IActionResult Test([FromQuery] string email)
{
    if (email == "TestInput")
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
    return Ok(false);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
http://example.com/api/Test?email=TestInput
```

Then a string would work.

Disclaimer: I do not know how Angular works, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Controller method that is tested with Postman and with payload "TestInput" and Content-Type: application/json

```
[HttpPost("Test")]
public bool Test([FromBody] string email)
{
   return email?.Equals("TestInput") == true;
}
```

Following description in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021779/14072498

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
}

const payload = 'TestInput';

this.client.post<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'weatherforecast/Test', `\"${payload}\"`, httpOptions);
```

Note

```
`\"${payload}\"`
```

can (should) be replaced with

```
JSON.stringify(payload)
```

but the latter did not work for a person that commented this answer.

Comment: It works using Postman, but not when sent by Angular as the string gets unquoted before being sent, you can test that by copying the `xhr` request from the browser and import it in postman

Comment: @RafiHenig: Several posts are indicating that missing content-type is causing this problem. By passing a simple string instead of a JSON, Angular fails to guess content-type. But, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I've tried setting `Contnet-Type` header to `Application/Json`  with both Postman and Angular, only the former works

Comment: @RafiHenig: Updated my answer with JSON.stringify('TestInput')