# How to send a string value in POST request body with Angular?

Tags: angular, http

I need to send an HTML string to the backend to be processed. To do this I am using Angular's `HttpClient`. However, the framework refuses to give me any meaningful error message other than a 400 response code. Below is my code.

Service method:

```
exportTestAsPdf(testHtml: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseTestApiUrl + "Print", `\"${testHtml}\"`, this.requestHeaders);
}
```

requestHeaders:

```
protected get requestHeaders(): { headers: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } } {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.accessToken}`,
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  });

  return { headers };
}
```

ASP.NET endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Print([FromBody] string testHtml)
{
    // Code here
}
```

It doesn't give me 404 so I know the endpoint is found. What is the problem?

I followed the answers in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354807/how-to-post-a-string-in-the-body-of-a-post-request-with-angular-4-3-httpclient) but those did not help me.

Comment: Maybe check logs in DevTools. It could be a CORS issue.`Console` or `Network` tab should provide you some meaningful error message.

Comment: I am using this environment quite extensively so it is not a CORS issue. I will check the tabs you mentioned.

Comment: I am assuming you are subscribing to `exportTestAsPdf` somewhere. `this.service.exportTestAsPdf('dd').subscribe({})` to generate API error

Comment: @Prabh I am subscribing ofc. I didn't want to include unnecessary parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send the value like this.

```
  exportTestAsPdf(testHtml: string): Observable<any> {
  const body = { data : "Print" +  `\"${testHtml}\"`};
        return this.http.post<any>(this.baseTestApiUrl , body, {this.requestHeaders});
    }
```

In your backend, declare string data type named data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use "${encodeURIComponent(testHtml)}" when posting your string